# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = L, \quad L \in R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In a question the answers say that:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = L, L \in R
$$

How?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In the denominator, multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ and then use the famous limit for the sine function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator by the argument of $\sin$, then use the $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x }{x}=1$ limit, the second term converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Worked, thank you.

Comment: @Alon feel free to accept the solution you liked

Answer (score 2):

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}} \sqrt n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n} $$

Use the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

The rest of the limit can be evaluated easily to be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works.